# How can I parse strings which have multiple URLs?

Tags: javascript, html

For example I have strings which has multiple URLs.

```js
var str = '"test.com","test2.com","test3.com/123,312","test4.com/123,312"'
```

I want to make array from this string.

at first I try to use `split(",")` however some URL has `","`.

Is there any good idea to separate these?

Comment: Why don't you just use `split('","')` instead?

Comment: @MichaelM., notice that the last 2 urls have commas within them. @whitebear, could you perhaps replace `","` with another delimiter, such as `"|"` or `";"` and then split based on that?

Comment: @mykaf Yes, but no URL has `","` in it; that delimiter is only between two URLs.

Comment: `const items = JSON.parse(\`[${str}]\`);`

Comment: @MichaelM., wouldn't that leave the first and last urls with mismatched quotation marks?

Comment: @mykaf That seems like a solvable problem since no URL has quotes in it.

Comment: @mykaf I usually use "|" when splitting text. Or encodeURIComponent

Comment: There aren't any `|` in that string, though. I'm not sure how `encodeURIComponent` is related.

Comment: @whitebear Please tell us by what rules the input string was formatted, ideally show us the code that generates it as output. Without a grammar, at least an informal one, we cannot tell you how to correctly parse the input. A single example is not enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regexp with a lookbehind assertion:

```js
var str = '"test.com","test2.com","test3.com/123,312","test4.com/123,312"'

console.log(str.match(/(?<=")[^,][^"]+/g));
```

Also you could just split the string:

```js
const str = '"test.com","test2.com","test3.com/123,312","test4.com/123,312"';
console.log(str.slice(1, -1).split('","'));
```

And a benchmark:

```
` Chrome/121
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                     n=62      |     n=620     |    n=6200     |    n=62000   
Alexander slice   1.00x x1m 102 | 1.00x x1m 101 | 1.00x x1m 103 | 1.00x x1m 103
Alexander regex   1.24x x1m 126 | 1.20x x1m 121 | 1.20x x1m 124 | 1.21x x1m 125
Chris Barr        1.23x x1m 125 | 1.24x x1m 125 | 1.24x x1m 128 | 1.25x x1m 129
vishal_g          3.22x x1m 328 | 3.23x x1m 326 | 3.12x x1m 321 | 3.12x x1m 321
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const $chunk = '"test.com","test2.com","test3.com/123,312","test4.com/123,312"';
let $input = $chunk;

// @benchmark vishal_g
$input.match(/"(.*?)"/g).map(function(url) {
  return url.replace(/"/g, '');
});

// @benchmark Chris Barr
$input.split(`","`).map(s => s.replace(/"/g, ''));

// @benchmark Alexander regex
$input.match(/(?<=")[^,][^"]+/g);

// @benchmark Alexander slice
$input.slice(1, -1).split('","');

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Comment: Nice, as I predicted splitting by `","` was the fastest, but the RegEx benchmark is helpful too. Also, I'd just like to say: I love this awesome benchmarking tool!

Answer (score 0):

If the string is split up by `","` (a quote, a comma, and a quote), then we have all the URL's which can maintain their internal commas.  Then we just have to remove any quotes that are left in each string of the array

```js
var str = '"test.com","test2.com","test3.com/123,312","test4.com/123,312"';
var urls = str.split(`","`).map(s => s.replace(/"/g, ''));
console.log(urls);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just pull the url from inside the quotes?

You can do it by regex `str.match(/".*?"/g).`.

Or by just doing `` str.split(`",`).map(url => url.substring(1)) ``. The `map` part just drops the leading quote.

Comment: you forgot the ending quote in the last word with splitting...

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you can use regular expressions to parse the string and extract the URLs. Here's how you can achieve that using JavaScript:

```
var str = '"test.com","test2.com","test3.com/123,312","test4.com/123,312"';
var urls = str.match(/"(.*?)"/g).map(function(url) {
  return url.replace(/"/g, '');
});

console.log(urls);
```

Explanation:

`str.match(/"(.*?)"/g)` uses a regular expression to match text enclosed in double quotes and returns an array of matched strings.

`.map(function(url) { return url.replace(/"/g, ''); })` removes the double quotes from each matched URL.

The `urls` array will contain the extracted URLs.

This code should work for your example string and handle URLs with commas as well.